# How to suppress group totals when there is only one detail record

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to not show the group footer when there is only 1 record in the group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out I can do it by using the conditional formatting on the suppress option for the group header and setting it to

```
Count({thefield}, {thegroup}) = 1
```

Comment: Also another cool trick: by taking advantage of the "Underlay following sections" option I can also get the group headers on the same line as the first record of the details.